Prove that $2(a+b+c)+\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\le abc$ if $a,b,c\gt0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=abc$
I started solving the problem by using the AM-GM inequality to show that $\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\ge a+b+c$
Multiplied both sides by 2 and added $\frac{a^3}{bc}$, $\frac{b^3}{ac}$, $\frac{c^3}{ab}$
So, $3(\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab})\ge 2(a+b+c)+\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}$
To prove the original inequality we need to show that  $3(\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab})\le abc$
With rearranging the inequality and exchanging $abc$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2$
$3(\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab})\le a^2+b^2+c^2\Rightarrow 3\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{abc}\le a^2+b^2+c^2$
Again I exchanged $abc$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and after rearranging the inequality I got $a^4+b^4+c^4 \le a^2b^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2$  which is untrue (can be shown by using the AM-GM inequality)
I'm unsure if the correct answer is that $2(a+b+c)+\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}\le abc$ is untrue or if I did something incorrectly.
Thank you for the help.

Use $\frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}=\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{abc}$ and divide by $a+b+c$ to get:
$$\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{abc(a+b+c)}+2 \le \frac{abc}{a+b+c} (\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc})^2 = \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{abc(a+b+c)}$$
(note that $\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc} = 1$).
Now we need to show that $\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 - a^4+b^4+c^4}{abc(a+b+c)} \ge 2$
$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 - a^4+b^4+c^4 = 2((ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2)$, so we need to show:
$$\frac{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2}{abc(a+b+c)} \ge 1$$, which follows from AM-GM applied to $(ab)^2,(bc)^2$ and two other pairs (then add them up).
